# How to move custom block in product detailed page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, static-block

I had created custom block and called in catalog_product_view.xml file but it is coming after the description now I need that block after the price.

For ref please find the below url aslo

https://icontiles.co.uk/calacatta-matt-white-marble-effect-porcelain-tile-600x600.html

[image]

This is code the I had put in catalog_product_view.xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="area-calculator" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">area-calculator</argument>
                     </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

How can I move above custom block to after price ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had created move element and i called my destination

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="area-calculator" before="product.info.social">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">area-calculator</argument>
                     </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

 <move element="area-calculator" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please below the code put in the `catalog_product_view.xml` file.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="custom-block" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom-block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <!-- Move custom block after price -->
        <move element="custom-block" destination="product.info.price" before="product.info.stock.sku"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

See the below screenshot for the result:-

[image: Move custom block after price]

**Note:-** Please change cms block name :  **custom-block** to **area-calculator**

**Thanks.**